# The problem in the field of array behavior is like a pointer

Tags: c++, console

I'm learning C++.

And I thought that `Array[i]=*(Array+i)` .

In the code below, if we remove the phrase within the comments(For Loop)

`*(x+1)` Not equal to When (For-Loop) Existed.
my compiler is mingw.

```
main()
{
    int x[10];
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
    cout<<"x"<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"--->"<<x[i]<<endl;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
cout<<*(x+1);

}
```

I expected the output of `*(x+1)` to be the same before and after remove for.

thanks and sorry about my grammar.

Comment: "_I'm learning C++_" And you tagged the question with [tag:c]? Btw, if whatever resource you're using to learn C++ suggests `main()`, then please throw it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, `x` in an automatic local variable and never initialized. The contents of the array members are *indeterminate*.

You cannot have any *expected* value there. Every time you execute, you'll get indeterminate values.